# ParseKit not matching my EOL symbols: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, regex, parsing, parsekit

The ParseKit adventure continues... and my next hurdle is trying to get newline symbols recognized.

Here's my grammar:

```
@symbolState = '\n';
@start = textline*;
textline = Any* eol;
eol = '\n';
```

Here's my test text:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The text is being read from a UTF-8 text file with Unix format (LF) line endings. I've verified that format both in Xcode (file inspector -> Text Settings) as well as externally, with TextWrangler.

And here's the relevant code:

```
#import "FileImporterThing.h"
#import <ParseKit/ParseKit.h>

@interface FileImporterThing ()
@property (nonatomic, retain)PKParser* parser;
- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchTextline:(PKAssembly *)a;
- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchEol:(PKAssembly *)a;
@end


@implementation FileImporterThing

@synthesize parser = _parser;

-(id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    // Have also tried "textline = Any* '\n';"
    NSString *g = @"@symbolState = '\n'; @start = textline*; textline = Any* eol; eol = '\n';";
    self.parser = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:g assembler:self];

    return self;
}

- (void)testParse
{
    // read string from UTF-8 file Unix (LF) line endings 
    // (this verified in project->file inspector->Text Settings and externally with TextWrangler)
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"LF-test" ofType:@"parsetext"];
/* file contains text:
1
2
3
4
5

*/
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [self.parser parse:s];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchEol:(PKAssembly *)a
{
    NSLog(@"eol found");// stack = %@", [a stack]);
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchTextline:(PKAssembly *)a
{
    NSLog(@"textline matched");
}

@end
```

But I'm afraid the paint just isn't drying! Have tried all sorts of variations on the above. I can't for the life of me get the parser to recognise a newline. I can probably work around this, by reading the file-buffer line by line (which might be more performant anyway?) but it would still be nice to have the option of matching '\n'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here. Two things I can contribute:

---

1.

I tried your example using a text file created in either TextMate or TextWrangler (saved as a .txt file), and everything seemed to work fine. My `-parser:didMatchEol:` and `-parser:didMatchTexline:` callbacks were called as expected.

If this is not working for you, maybe try starting with in-memory string input to see if at least that will work:

```
NSString *s = @"foo bar\nbaz bat\n";
[parser parse:s];
```

Anyway, here's my code from `DebugAppDelegate.m` which is working for me with either in-memory input or on-disk input:

```
- (void)doTestGrammar {
    NSString *g = @"@symbolState = '\n'; @start = textline*; textline = Any* eol; eol = '\n';";
    PKParser *p = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:g assembler:self];
    //NSString *s = @"foo bar\nbaz bat\n";
    NSString *path = [@"~/Desktop/text.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [p parse:s];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchEol:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchTextline:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);
}
```

---

2.

I was actually a little surprised that your example worked however, as I thought your use of the `Any*` production would greedily consume the `\n` tokens at the end of the line, thus leaving nothing for the `eol` production to match.

However, as I mentioned, this was not a problem when I ran your example (against ParseKit HEAD of trunk).

Still, for good measure, I would probably recommend altering your `textline` production to this:

```
textline = ~eol* eol;
```

the definition of this production should be read as:

**zero or more tokens NOT matched by `eol`, followed by one token matched by `eol`**

`~` is the boolean negation operator in ParseKit grammar syntax.

After making this change to my example code, everything still worked as expected.

---

If you still can't get it working after these two tips, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate answer Todd! Of course you're right, my mistake, sorry - turned out to be a silly case-sensitive issue causing my test file not to be found. But then I was then stumped as to why my real code wasn't working. It turns out that hardcoding the grammar works, but reading it from a file doesn't: '\n' seems to be interpreted differently, as a literal? Difficult even putting my exact problem into words, suffice to say, if I read from file, then pass the string to NSLog I see each '/n' printed in full. But the hardcoded string sends real newlines to the console. Any tips?

Comment: If that was not very clear, then just try adapting the small example above, to read the grammar from file too. Does that work for you?

Comment: Ah, I see. Hm, yeah that's tricky. Maybe try using '\\n' in the file-based version of the grammar? I'll try to find some time to look into this later today. Might be a bug in ParseKit, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought about '\\n' too but doesn't work :( What *does* work is a physical newline inside the single quotes. Not too elegant, but keeps me rolling at least :)

Comment: @Todd Is there a place where I can find a list of the ParseKit syntax?  I seem to be hunter-gathering ParseKit syntax by reading every ParseKit forum post on the web. Thanks.

Comment: Rich's finding that '\n' matches didn't work for him is an important point. I believe it is because Cocoa interprets the '\n' character in an `NSString` literal differently a newline in a file that is imported using `stringWithContentsOfFile`. This is possible because there are a handful of unicode characters that can represent a newline. See the Apple documentation for `kCFCharacterSetNewline`.  We need to match the specific unicode newline character in the grammar file with the specific unicode newline character in the string we are parsing.